# Call Class from String - Java

Tags: java, string

How do I call a class from a String?
For Example.

```
String choice;
System.out.print("Enter your movie name:")
String=sc.nextString();

if(String=="MyMovie")
{
```

Can I use:

```
choice.main(null);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here. Plus it looks like you've missed code out.

Comment: I've a feeling that you wish to use the value in `choice` as the class name and you want to call the main method of that class. Am I right?

Comment: I think @Ɍ.Ɉ is right. Typically, if you need a pattern like that, your design is wrong (you're confusing classes with objects).

Answer (score 4):

Try this code.

```
String choice;
System.out.print("Enter your movie name:")
choice = sc.nextString();
if(choice.equals("MyMovie")) {
    //do something but not choice.main(null)
}
```

Comment: nice way of saying it :)

Comment: Hm. `equalsTo` should probably be `equals`?

Comment: yup.... sorry, that was in the middle of objective c programming, (isEqualsTo)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call a class from a string, but rather a method depending on a string in parameter.

For example

```
if("MyMovie".equals(myString))
{
  myclass.method();
}
```

Beware, use "equals" to compare strings, not "==".

If you need to create an object, you should instantiate it, or make the method you want to call static. I would guess that since you are trying to call "main", you want to call a static method from an other class, and in this case all you need to do is

```
MyClass.myMethod()
```

Honestly, I think, you should look at a java tutorial first.